# Python import lib analogue to "import * from XXX"

Tags: python

I have following structure of configuration files:

```
app
  \config
     \development
        \__init__.py
        \settings.py
        \app_config.py
     \production
        \__init__.py
        \settings.py
        \app_config.py
     \testingpy
        \settings.py
        \app_config.py
     \settinngs.py
     \app_config.py
```

Actually `app.config.settings` just check environment variable `RUNTIME_ENV` (which could be `development|production|testing`, equivalent to one of `config`'s subfolders) and load corresponding settings.

I know only about importing with `importlib` which return to me module as local variable and I forced to write something like that:

```
SCALA_URL = imported_settings.SCALA_URL
REDIS_URL = imported_settings.REDIS_URL
SOME_SETTINGS_VAR = imported_settings.REDIS_URL
.... tons of duplicated strings here, i.e. variables names are the same ...
```

Is there way to do something similar to python's expression: `from config.${RUNTIME_ENV}.settings import *`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) is mutable.  You could do something like this:

```
imported_foo = importlib.import_module('foo')
globals().update(vars(imported_foo))
```

Note that this imports underscore-prefixed things into the global namespace.  If you want to exclude those, write a dictionary comprehension that only includes the things you want.  For example:

```
globals().update({name: value 
                  for name, value in vars(imported_foo).items()
                  if not name.startswith('_')})
```

This *does not work* with `locals()`, which returns a read-only value.  It is not reasonably possible to do that (`import *` into a non-global namespace), because Python has to know the names of all local variables at compile time in order to generate the correct `LOAD_FOO` instructions in the bytecode (along with a variety of other interesting problems such as identifying the variables captured by a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29)).  You will find that `import *` is illegal inside a function or class:

```
>>> def foo():
...     from foo import *
... 
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: import * only allowed at module level
>>>
```

That's not just a matter of "`import *` is bad design."  It's a fundamental language limitation and can't be worked around with `importlib`.